# Synchronous Spell Checking For Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, spell-checking

I am trying to check the spelling of individual words synchronously in Node.js. All of the libraries I have found (spellchecker, teacher, speller, ...) have asynchronous calls, and that doesn't work for me.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
function mycheck(w) {
    spell.check(w, function(err, correct, suggestions) {
        if (correct) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, `mycheck` is always undefined, because `spell.check` is asynchronous. Also, I can't just make `mycheck` be asynchronous, because that doesn't fit with the rest of my program.

Is there another way to spell check (synchronously) or a way to make this work synchronously? I am ok with using some kind of "helper" package to make the function synchronous.

Thanks so much!
:D

Comment: You say your async code does not fit with rest of the program. Why did you make the rest synchronous ? Node's strength is the asynchronous behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node.JS is an asynchronous language, don't try and force it to become synchronous, make mycheck async instead, and adapt the rest of your application before it can't be salvaged anymore

Comment: This seemed to be the best approach. Should've thought of that sooner. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would have been better to say "NodeJS is built with _asynchronocity_ in mind" than to say _"NodeJS is an asynchronous language"_ - NodeJS is not a language.